# Elasticsearch - what's the best way to search conditions with both suggester and other filters?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to convert query condition from a relational database like:

`select ... from ... where name like 'ABC%' and grade = 3 and city = 'Munich'`

To ElasticSearch query string?

The `name like 'ABC%'` is a prefix search, which I prefer use [Completion Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html). While it seems cannot add other filters to `Completion Suggester`. How to handle `grade = 3 and city = 'Munich'` conditions?

[Context Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html) does not help because `grade` and `city` options are too many.

Comment: what is wrong with simple bool query?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 `bool` query can handle "con_1 AND con_2 AND con_3", but how to handle `like 'ABC%'`? I only know `Completion Suggester` can handle `like 'ABC%'` case. But I'm not sure how to combine `Completion Suggester` to `bool` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this query?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "city": "Munich"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "grade": {
              "value": "2"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "name": "abc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I think you can simulate sql like with [match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix)

Does this help?

Comment: Awesome, it works! It seems `match_phrase_prefix` seems have very similar function with `Completion Suggester`. While I'm wondering whether the performance is worse than `Completion Suggester` because `Completion Suggester` is building FST in memory (in my case performance is not very critical, I'm just want to know more about these 2:)

Comment: `Completion Suggester` is used to provide autocomplete feature, so if user types _fe_  in search box, you can give _federer_, _fedex_ as options. while `match_phrase_prefix` is a type of `match` query you use when you want to find string with some prefix like in your case.

Comment: My case is also autocomplete feature. User input "fe", will return "feature", "feet", "feet foot cool".

Comment: When use `match_phrase_prefix`, input "fe", it not only return "feet", but also return "feet foot cool", which performs same with `Completion Suggester`... (in my opinion, prefix is only for current word, which means "fe" will produce "feet" but not "feet foot cool")

Comment: you are right, prefix is only for current word but I am confused now. you fire suggest query when user is typing and then when he hits search button then you can query with all the search criteria. Both `suggester` and `phrase_prefix_query` are for different use cases.

Comment: When use `match_phrase_prefix`, input "fe", will return "feature", "feet", "feet foot cool". While if use default tokenizer, when input "foo", it will return "feet foot cool". I use `keyword` tokenizer, when input "foo", it returns nothing, which is fine.

Comment: If I only want to get `name`, I can add field `name`, while the returned names may be duplicate, like `["foot", "foot", "feet"]`. How do I get distinct names? In my case, I don't think aggregation helps.